# Strip pagespeed module extension from image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have this jQuery function on my site that adds a **share on Facebook button** to images, which have worked great.

Problem is, now I have installed Google's Pagespeed Module on my server, to make things a little faster. Works like a charm, except for one thing:

Images now get the pagespeed extension, which Facebook doesn't seem to like.

So, what I'm looking for is a function to get the image src (this is already in place), strip the added pagespeed extensions, and send back the "original" image src.

I'm fetching the image src like this:

```
img = $(this).attr('src');
```

What I don't have is a function to strip the pagespeed extension after this function.

The google pagespeed images look's like this:

http://my-site.com/wp-content/uploads/700x524ximagename700x524.jpg.pagespeed.ic.9rlwkDUtDK.webp

The problem is, there are two parts needed to be stripped out:

**700x524x** that appears **before** the image name...

...and everything **after the file extension** (*.pagespeed.ic.9rlwkDUtDK.webp*)

Is there some guru out there that can suggest me a solution to this problem perhaps?

Thanks!

// Jens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a regular expression to match the parts of the string you do (and don't) want to keep, and then you can use a backreference to extract the original file name. The filename here will be in the matched group, `$1`.

```
\d*x\d*x(.*)\.pagespeed.*
```

See example at https://regex101.com/r/jR8fI3/1

In javascript:

```
var image = "700x524ximagename700x524.jpg.pagespeed.ic.9rlwkDUtDK.webp";
var original = image.replace(/\d*x\d*x(.*)\.pagespeed.*/, "$1");
alert(original);
```

See example at http://jsfiddle.net/1afhzfxa/

Comment: That's awesome @doublesharp ! If I also need to keep the path to the file, the http://mysite/wp-content... etc, is this possible?

Comment: For sure, in fact, it should just work. If not you might need to use another matching group for the path and then use `$1$2` in the `replace()`.

Comment: Worth noting that it is using ".pagespeed" to match the start of what the plugin is appending, so if you happened to have an image with that in the filename, it would break. You could get more specific with the pattern matching though - if you aren't familiar with regex definitely do some research as it is quite powerful.

Comment: Will totally do that! Thank's a lot for your help!